# jackson arraynode

Tags: json, parsing, jackson

I have a input json object that contains a array as shown below:

```
[{"key11":"value11","key12":"value12"},
{"key21":"value21","key22":"value22"},
...
{"keyn1":"valuen1","keyn2":"valuen2"}]
```

I would like to use jackson parser ,firstly, to identify the number of rows and secondly, print only the values on the screen. I want it to be as lightweight as possible. Can anyone point me to a direction?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that a `row` is one of the entries in a `ArrayNode` the following simple approach may be useful. It uses the `JsonNode` abstraction instead of a series of nested `Map` objects which I personally prefer since `JsonNode` provides a series of utility methods that are helpful when dealing with *this kind of data* (data where the structure is possibly unknown or very dynamic so that it can't be easily transformed to a POJO).

The testcase below illustrates how to find the number of rows and how to print the values. To get hold of the values the method `JsonNode.elements()` is used and the number of rows is simply a call to the `size()`-method.

```
public class ArrayNodeTest {
    @Test
    public void verifySizeAndPrintRows() throws IOException {
        final String jsonStr =
                "[{\"key11\":\"value11\",\"key12\":\"value12\"},\n" +
                        "{\"key21\":\"value21\",\"key22\":\"value22\"},\n" +
                        "{\"keyn1\":\"valuen1\",\"keyn2\":\"valuen2\"}]";

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(jsonStr);

        // Verify size
        Assert.assertEquals(3, jsonNode.size());

        // And print rows
        for (final JsonNode row : jsonNode) {
            final Iterable<JsonNode> iterable = () -> row.elements();
            iterable.forEach(elem -> System.out.println(elem.asText()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> to identify the number of rows

What's a "row"?  Is a key/value pair a row?  Is an element of the JSON array (no matter how many key/value pairs it contains) a row?

> print only the values on the screen

Jackson has nothing to do with printing anything on any screens.  Jackson can be used to populate a Java data structure from the input JSON, and the populated Java data structure can then be used however you want.

Given the JSON structure in the original question, a simple solution would be to bind to a list (or array) of maps, and then just iterate through the list of maps, accessing all of the values.  Following is such an example.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, String>[] maps = mapper.readValue(new File("input.json"), Map[].class);
    for (Map<String, String> map : maps)
    {
      for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
      {
        System.out.println(entry.getValue());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
value11
value12
value21
value22
valuen1
valuen2
```